# Unable to return the "valid" field from the parsed dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have the json in the following format:

```
myDict =
{
  "Garden": {
    "GroundFloor": {
      "@loc": "porch",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "1",
      "InfoList": {
        "status": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "20C"
        },
        "count": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "1"
        }
      }
    },
      "TopFloor": {
      "@loc": "backyard",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "2",
      "InfoList": {
        "status": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "20D"
        },
        "count": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
"BackYard": {
    "GroundFloor": {
      "@loc": "porch",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "3",
      "InfoList": {
        "status": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "20C"
        },
        "count": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "1"
        }
      }
    },
      "TopFloor": {
      "@loc": "backyard",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "4",
      "InfoList": {
        "status": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "20D"
        },
        "count": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
... many more nested layers...
}
```

I store this into a dictionary and need to perform some processing on this.

For a given "Tid", I want to be able to return the "@default" value in the "status" part. For example, if I request for "Tid" = 1, I should get the following output.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{ "Tid": "1",
  "status": "0"  -->this is the value from the @default attribute
} 
# note that the "status" value is the attribute @default.
```

I have the following method as of now but it returns me this and I am not understanding why.

```
{ "Tid": null,
  "status": null
}
```

My Method:

```
def get_system_state(myDict, id):
    for i in  ["id", "@default"]:
        print (myDict.get(i))
    if any(c == id_type for c in myDict.values()):
        yield {i: myDict.get(i) for i in ["id", "@default"]}
    else:
        for i in myDict.values():
            if isinstance(i, dict):
                yield from get_system_state(i, id_type)
```

```
# Called by
get_system_state(myDict, 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `TopFloor"` you miss the quote

Comment: Goto this website and validate the json - [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @Nitin validated it and updated it.

Comment: @LauraSmith Let me check why this is happening. Will revert back to u

Comment: @LauraSmith What is your expected output?

Comment: @bharatk I updated it in the code. It is labelled as EXPECTED OUTPUT.

Comment: @LauraSmith what about rest of part of the dictionary if a condition is a match, or you just want to add `status` as key and `@default` is value outside of the nested dictionary if the condition match

Comment: I want to be able to return the result with the "Tid" and its value and the "status" and its value which is the @default when I query for a specific "Tid" in the get_system_state method. To this method, I pass the myDict and the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple recursion:

```
data = {'Garden': {'GroundFloor': {'@loc': 'porch', '@myID': '35C', 'Tid': '1', 'InfoList': {'status': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '20C'}, 'count': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '1'}}}, 'TopFloor': {'@loc': 'backyard', '@myID': '35C', 'Tid': '2', 'InfoList': {'status': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '20D'}, 'count': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '2'}}}}, 'BackYard': {'GroundFloor': {'@loc': 'porch', '@myID': '35C', 'Tid': '3', 'InfoList': {'status': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '20C'}, 'count': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '1'}}}, 'TopFloor': {'@loc': 'backyard', '@myID': '35C', 'Tid': '4', 'InfoList': {'status': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '20D'}, 'count': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '2'}}}}}
def get_id(d, id):
   if isinstance(d, dict) and d.get('Tid') == id:
      yield {'Tid':d['Tid'], 'status':d['InfoList']['status']['@default']}
   for i in getattr(d, 'values', lambda :[])():
      yield from get_id(i, id)

print(list(get_id(data, '1')))
```

Output:

```
[{'Tid': '1', 'status': '0'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just change your dictionary `"Tid": "2","InfoList": { "status": { "@default": "1","@myID": "20D"},` @default value for testing purpose.

- [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) methods returns "True" if all characters in the string are digits, Otherwise, It returns "False".

**Ex.**

```
myDict ={
  "Garden": {
    "GroundFloor": {
      "@loc": "porch",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "1",
      "InfoList": {"status": { "@default": "0","@myID": "20C"},
      "count": {"@default": "0","@myID": "1"}
      }
    },
      "TopFloor": {
      "@loc": "backyard",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "2",
      "InfoList": { "status": { "@default": "1","@myID": "20D"},
      "count": {"@default": "0","@myID": "2" }
      }
    }
  }
}


def get_system_state(myDict, id):
    for k,v in myDict['Garden'].items():
        for x in v:
            if 'Tid' in v and v['Tid'] is not None and v['Tid'].isdigit() and int(v['Tid']) == id:
                return [{'Tid':id,'status':v['InfoList']['status']['@default']}]

new_dict = get_system_state(myDict, 1)
print(new_dict)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'Tid': 1, 'status': '0'}]
```

if you pass `id=2`

```
new_dict = get_system_state(myDict, 2)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'Tid': 2, 'status': '1'}]
```

**Update:**

if a dictionary doesn't have the "Garden" as a top-level dictionary

```
def get_system_state(myDict, id):
    for k1,v1 in myDict.items():
        for k,v in v1.items():
            for x in v:
                if 'Tid' in v and v['Tid'] is not None and v['Tid'].isdigit() and int(v['Tid']) == id:
                    return [{'Tid':id,'status':v['InfoList']['status']['@default']}]
```

Comment: For instance if the dictionary doesnt have the "Garden" string as the top level node, how do I make it generic for any case?

Comment: I updated the myDict in the question to reflect what I mean.

Comment: @LauraSmith Try now.

Comment: One last question, is it possible to  have the ```return {'Tid':id,'status':v['InfoList']['status']['@default']}``` return a list instead?

Comment: I tried this ```return list({'Tid':id,'status':v['InfoList']['status']['@default']})```. It gives me error ```'NoneType' object is not iterable```.

Comment: @Laura Smith Means like this `[{'Tid': 2, 'status': '1'}]` or `[2,0]`

Comment: like the [{'Tid': 2, 'status': '1'}]  as I want to send it to the ```jsonify``` method. Thats why I want to return a list and do something like this if possible, ```jsonify(key_list if not key_list else key_list[0])```.

Comment: @LauraSmith Means I'm not getting any error. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
def get_system_state(myDict, id):
    garden_details = myDict.get("Garden", None)
    if garden_details:
        for floor in garden_details:
            Tid = garden_details[floor].get(str("Tid"), None)
            if Tid == str(id):
                return {'Tid': Tid, 'status': garden_details[floor]['InfoList']['status']['@default']}
```

Check if this works for you.

Comment: I want to make it more generic rather than using the string "Garden". I update myDict to show this.

Comment: `garden_details = list(myDict.values())[0]` use this instead of `garden_details = myDict.get("Garden", None)` if the position is fixed.